# Rebuild Execution Plan In Sql Server 2012 on Stored Procedures Using Specific Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have couples of `stored procedure's` that are using `Product` table,I want to re-build the execution plan of all the `stored procedure's` that are using specific table `Product`?Kindly guide me,how to achieve this?I am using sql server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in following way:

```
 USE YourDatabaseName;
    GO
    EXEC sp_recompile N'Product';
    GO
```